# Dynamic Paint Image Sequence

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, image, dynamic-paint

How can the Blender User produce more usable bandwidth when creating images sequences from Dynamic Paint?

As an example I may want to use a different color where wave data is active.

[image]

Histogram. Image above.

[image]

Accentuated/Mapped Data which is consistent with some scheme of thinking.  Not Random. Image above.

For example the surface type of Waves did not use much bandwidth.  Though I may have a separate question to set expectations.

**Current Situation which is a Problem**

File Formats

- PNG - uses @1% of the potential color value

  - GIMP or Blender histogram
- OpenEXR (EXR) - uses @3% of the potential color value.

  - GIMP will not open EXR.
  - XnViewMP histogram

The color value is a measurement of the brightness of a color.

**Desired**

I would like to use near 100% of the color value range.

**Related Success**

Images produced by Dynamic Paint with Wave and Paint information.
Histograms are needed to detect the color information.
Color differences are too subtle to detect with this Blender Users eye.
Color is remapped with the color ramp.

Blender Internal Render

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenEXR instead PNG, it has 32-bit float per channel. Unused channels will be compressed

Comment: Small improvement.  Somewhat.  It might be too boring to explain or not enough testing.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic paint canvas has an initial value, this can be set to a chosen colour.

[image: canvas colour]

The dynamic paint brush can be set to paint a specific colour.

[image: brush colour]

The difference between the two colour settings will be the range  that you get in your result, if one is set to black and the other white you will get the largest range that is possible.

Comment: Surface types Waves and Displace do not offer the Initial Color. Paint Does

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger yes I did overlook the wave part. I would say waves don't bake to image sequence and report that as a bug.

Comment: Something non random and perhaps meaningful is baked for wave in a limited range.  Original question edited.

Comment: please see above perhaps the comment targets are not working.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I found why I didn't see any colour change last night, I can get up to 0.03 variation in each colour channel. I say it is a bug, baking waves to image calculates within too small a range. It is baking a displacement map so it doesn't even have to stay within the 0-1 range when saving to exr.

Comment: Well if you have the power for an immediate change then so be it.  I have  a different question posted which ask about the utility of such data.  My recent experiences with Dynamic Paint leave me with too many doubts.